# Angular BSModal - unable to pass data during edit item

Tags: angular

I want to pass an id in BSModal. Below is my modal open code in `.ts` file:

```
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
...
...
openModalEdit(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
    template,
    Object.assign({ignoreBackdropClick:true, keyboard:false, class: 'gray modal-lg'})
    );
  this.modalRef.content.id = 220;
  console.log("Open Modal event")
}
```

This is the html code:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="openModalEdit(template2)" class="dropdown-item">Edit</a></li>

<ng-template #template2>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Edit Genre</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideModal(template)">
                <img src="/assets/images/close-icon.png" alt="">
            </button>
        </div>
    <app-edit-genre (closeModal)="hideModal()"></app-edit-genre>
</ng-template>
```

Within the `.ts` file in the modal, I have the below code:

```
export class EditGenreComponent implements OnInit {
  public id: any;
  ...
}
```

Within the `.html` file in the modal, I have the below code:

```
<label class="required">Genre {{id}}</label>
```

It show me the error in console

> Cannot set property 'id' of null

Also, in the modal I see the following:

> Genre [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

In Angular BsModal you can pass data as an object when the modal appears. For example :

HTML :

```
<div>
  <button (click)="show()">Show</button>
</div>
```

TS:
Here the `ShowComponent` is the modal component

```
  show() {
    const initialState = {
        user: "Guest"
      };
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ShowComponent,{initialState});
  }
```